# Is it necessary to password_hash again when first password_hash already valid ? I'm newbie

Tags: php, hash, passwords, bcrypt, php-password-hash

I read and followed a PHP documentation regarding `password_hash` and got this:

```
    <?php
// first determine if a supplied password is valid
$options = ['cost' => 12,];

$hashedPassword = password_hash($plaintextPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options);
if (password_verify($plaintextPassword, $hashedPassword)) {

    // now determine if the existing hash was created with an algorithm that is
    // no longer the default
    if (password_needs_rehash($hashedPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)) {

        // create a new hash with the new default
        $newHashedPassword = password_hash($plaintextPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        // and then save it to your data store
        //$db->update(...);
    }
}
?>
```

I really want to know is it necessary to hash_password again when 1st hash already valid.

Comment: What's `hash_password`?

Answer (score 1):

The second check is looking to see if the password was encrypted with the current PASSWORD_DEFAULT.

It is more of a PHP compatibility / ongoing security thing than a password check.

Have a look at:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

The old days of `md5($password)` are gone...

Comment: thz and 1 more question is should i put $option = cost 12 to New password_hash $newHashedPassword ?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the second invocation of `password_hash` is not necessary. Nevertheless it's enormously useful and shouldn't be omitted! As Mark already mentioned, this second invocation helps to keep your stored hashes up to date.

But there's a very important flaw in your code-snippet. The part you copied from the docs is fine, but the way you extended it is not correct.
So what's happening? The first invocation of `password_hash` creates a hash from the *plaintext password*. Then `password_verify` is invoked with the parameters `$plaintextPassword`, `$hashedPassword`. That's the problematic part. This invocation will always yield `TRUE` because you're verifying that the plaintext password matches the just created hash of itself. This will never fail, which eventually makes the condition useless.

The mistake is your first invocation of `password_hash`. At this point you wouldn't hash the `$plaintextPassword`. Instead you should retrieve the already stored password-hash of that user from your database. Next you would then invoke `password_verify` in a way like this: `password_verify($plaintextPassword, $hashedPasswordFromDatabase))`. This makes sure that the entered plaintext password matches the password-hash you already know.

```
// drop that line
//$hashedPassword = password_hash($plaintextPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options); 

// and replace it with something like this
$hashedPasswordFromDatabase = $db->getPasswordHashForUserId(42);

// match the plaintext pw an the pw from db 
if (password_verify($plaintextPassword, $hashedPasswordFromDatabase)) 
{
    ...
```

Then `password_needs_rehash` checks if that password-hash (taken from database) is still up to date. If it finds out the hash is deprecated, the condition comes true and `password_hash` is invoked again. To understand why this is useful, imagine the following: You publish your website the next days. Users create accounts and the [currently active hashing-algorithm **CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://php.net/manual/en/password.constants.php) is used to create the users' hashes. Your site becomes so successful, it's still active in 2020. By that time (most likely very much earlier) better hashing-algorithms become the default. New users' passwords would then automatically being created with that better algorithm, because you're using the constant `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` which will return that other hashing-algorithm in another PHP version. For new users, this fine. But already existent users' passwords wouldn't be *rehashed* and virtually wouldn't be *updated* if you hadn't that second invocation of `password_hash` in your code.

Long story short: Have that second invocation in your snippet, to make your code more future-proof.

---

To address your other question:

A cost of `12` may be fine right now, but that's a value you should adjust from time to time. Taken [from the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#refsect1-function.password-hash-notes):

> It is recommended that you test this function on your servers, and adjust the cost parameter so that execution of the function takes less than 100 milliseconds on interactive systems.

So you should increase it in way that it produces the desired delay on your server hardware. But also note that increasing it too much [*could* make you vulnerable](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12101/prevent-denial-of-service-attacks-against-slow-hashing-functions) to denial of service attacks.

For a very detailed introduction into password hashing, have a look at this great article at crackstation: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm